# Update index with script in ElasticSearch Bulk JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch **Update** action with [Upserts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/docs-update.html#upserts) to create or update an existing document in the current Index, when doing in the [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-6-5.html#api-bulk-6-5) api like this

```
{
                    index: myIndex,
                    type: '_doc',
                    body: [
                    { index:  {_id: docItemID1 } },
                    docItem1,
                    { index:  {_id: docItemID2 } },
                    docItem2
]
                }
```

This works ok. Now I would like to update / append a new value to a `tag` field in the document item using the `scripted_upsert` flag and the `script` update action so something like:

```
{
   "scripted_upsert":true,
    "script" : {
        "source": "if ( !ctx._source.tags.contains(params.tag) ) ctx._source.tag.concat( params.tag)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : "blue"
        }
    },
    "upsert" : {
        "tag" : ["red","green"]
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use the `scripted_upsert` to take the best of the two worlds, so I imagine something like this - if it is correct (that is my question)

```
    {
        "script" : {
            "source": "if ( !ctx._source.tags.contains(params.tag) ) ctx._source.tag.concat( params.tag)",
            "lang": "painless",
            "params" : {
                "tag" : myNewTag
            }
        },
        "upsert" : docItem
    }
```

where `docItem` will contain a `tag` item to be updated. This tag items is a comma separated list of tags like `red,green`.

Is this approach correct? If so which is the right body for the `bulk` api i.e. when using the `body` as `[]` of actions having an update `script` with plus `scripted_upsert` flag for one or more items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, the [docs say](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/docs-update.html#_literal_scripted_upsert_literal):

> If you would like your script to run regardless of whether the document exists or not - [...] - then set `scripted_upsert` to true

So having both "upsert" and "script" sections is the way to go, but you have to keep the `"scripted_upsert":true` (which is missing from the last snippet).

Using the elasticsearch-js lib, it goes like this:

```
await client.bulk({
  index: 'myIndex',
  type: 'myType',
  body [
    { update: { _id: docId } },
    { script: { source, params }, scripted_upsert: true, upsert: docItem },
  ],
});
```